# Retrofit 2 parsing json , starting with array

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

Hope you are doing well .

I found a problem which is really weird . I get the response via retrofit 2 and wanna pars it via gson . The Whole response is like this ,

```
[ {"id":1,"name":"x","family":"y"},{"id":2,"name":"a","family":"b"},... ]
```

I have been testing many ways , but the problem is whenever I want to get response from body . The size of list is zero or null .

Can you show me the best way to parse this type of json .

If you want the code , I`ll show you there .

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MediJahed...Plz try my solution below and let me know in case of concern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `Retrofit` libray to web service calling than u will have to parse the Json using the POGO class like

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class YourPareseClass{

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("family")
@Expose
private String family;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getFamily() {
return family;
}

public void setFamily(String family) {
this.family = family;
}

}
```

As you know that the response is in the JsonArray than , you need to handle the response are as follow:-

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<YourPareseClass>>(){}.getType();
Collection<YourPareseClass> YOUR_RESONSE_ARRAY = gson.fromJson("YOUR_JSON_RESONSE", collectionType);  ///YOUR_RESONSE_ARRAY  contains all yours response in the Array
```

Comment: Grate , Still I dont know why the retrofit and gson builder can not part this damn response , but your solution works as a charm !

Thx man

Comment: @MehdiJahedManesh ..Happy to help bro :)

Comment: @MehdiJahedManesh ...Actually , we have to specify that the response is in the Array than we have to use the TypeToken ...Otherwise By default  it thinks that the resonse which is coming from server in the JsonObject  but our response is Array than conflict occured..And u get the null at the end..

Answer (score 4):

Its an array of objects. Say your object is of type `X` and your `JSON` string response is in variable Y then you should be parse it in following way

```
List<X> list =  (List<X>)new Gson().fromJSON(Y)
```

And your retrofit service call should look like this

```
@GET("/apiurl")
Call<List<X>> getListOfX(...)
```

Comment: this helped me .

Answer (score 0):

Use @Headers, passing "Accept: application/json":

```
@GET("/list")
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
Call<List<User>> getList()
```